# Touch, and drag/drop events are broken when importing calendar with webpack

Tags: fullcalendar, webpack

The calendar still loads, however it just spits out an error as soon as you attempt to click or drag on something:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'isAnimating' of undefined

I've initialized the calendar using the following code, the calendar loads, with some issues:

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react/addons';


React.initializeTouchEvents(true);

require("font-awesome-webpack");

//Calendar css
require('styles/normalize.css');
require('styles/main.css');
require('../../../../bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css');
require('../../../../bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.print.css');
var $ = require('../../../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery');


//Calendar js
require('../../../../bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar');


const DashboardHandler = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function(){
        console.log('clicked');
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '2015-02-12',
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end) {
                var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                var eventData;
                if (title) {
                    eventData = {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end
                    };
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
                }
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: '2015-02-01'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: '2015-02-07',
                    end: '2015-02-10'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2015-02-09T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2015-02-16T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Conference',
                    start: '2015-02-11',
                    end: '2015-02-13'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2015-02-12T10:30:00',
                    end: '2015-02-12T12:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: '2015-02-12T12:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2015-02-12T14:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Happy Hour',
                    start: '2015-02-12T17:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Dinner',
                    start: '2015-02-12T20:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: '2015-02-13T07:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    url: 'http://google.com/',
                    start: '2015-02-28'
                }
            ]
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log("RENDER")
        return (
            <div className='client-dashboard'>
                <div id='calendar'></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

export default DashboardHandler;
```

I have a webpack config file that looks like:

```
/*
 * Webpack development server configuration
 *
 * This file is set up for serving the webpack-dev-server, which will watch for changes and recompile as required if
 * the subfolder /webpack-dev-server/ is visited. Visiting the root will not automatically reload.
 */
'use strict';
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {

  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    publicPath: '/assets/'
  },

  cache: true,
  debug: true,
  // Sourcemaps are enabled. If this is too slow, set it to false.
  devtool: "eval-source-map",
    noInfo: true, //  --no-info option
  entry: [
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      './src/scripts/components/main.js'
  ],

  stats: {
    colors: true,
    reasons: true
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      'styles': path.join(__dirname, 'src/styles'),
      'components': path.join(__dirname, 'src/scripts/components/'),
      'actions': path.join(__dirname, 'src/scripts/actions/'),
      'stores': path.join(__dirname, 'src/scripts/stores/'),
      'jquery': path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery'),
      'jQueryUi': path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components/fullcalendar/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min'),
      'moment': path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components/moment/src/moment')
    }
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [{
      test: /\.js(x)?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'jsxhint?babel'
    }],
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js(x)?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'react-hot!babel'
    }, {
      test: /\.less/,
      loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!less-loader'
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
    }, {
      test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
      loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
    },
    { test:  /\.(woff|woff2)$/,   loader: "url-loader?prefix=font/&limit=5000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
    { test: /\.ttf$/,    loader: "file-loader" },
    { test: /\.eot$/,    loader: "file-loader" },
    { test: /\.svg$/,    loader: "file-loader" },
        { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff" },
        { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }

    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ]

};
```

Jquery and all of the calendars dependancies appear to be defined. The issue is being thrown in the following function in the calendar source code:
    // Causes the element to stop following the mouse. If shouldRevert is true, will animate back to original position.
    // `callback` gets invoked when the animation is complete. If no animation, it is invoked immediately.
    stop: function(shouldRevert, callback) {
        var _this = this;
        var revertDuration = this.options.revertDuration;

```
    function complete() {
        this.isAnimating = false;
        _this.destroyEl();

        this.top0 = this.left0 = null; // reset state for future updatePosition calls

        if (callback) {
            callback();
        }
    }

    if (this.isFollowing && !this.isAnimating) { // disallow more than one stop animation at a time
        this.isFollowing = false;

        $(document).off('mousemove', this.mousemoveProxy);

        if (shouldRevert && revertDuration && !this.isHidden) { // do a revert animation?
            this.isAnimating = true;
            this.el.animate({
                top: this.top0,
                left: this.left0
            }, {
                duration: revertDuration,
                complete: complete
            });
        }
        else {
            complete();
        }
    }
},
```

It looks like a really weird scoping issue caused by webpack, I'm at a loss as to how to fix it. Based on the stack trace, it also looks like the touch start event doesn't even fire:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'isAnimating' of
>   undefinedcomplete @ fullcalendar.js?2811:2551stop @
>   fullcalendar.js?2811:2577dragStop @ fullcalendar.js?2811:3761trigger @
>   fullcalendar.js?2811:2137dragStop @ fullcalendar.js?2811:2090dragStop
>   @ fullcalendar.js?2811:2409stopDrag @
>   fullcalendar.js?2811:2080stopListening @
>   fullcalendar.js?2811:2103mouseup @ fullcalendar.js?2811:2071(anonymous
>   function) @ fullcalendar.js?2811:760dispatch @
>   jquery.js?0403:4435jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle @
>   jquery.js?0403:4121

Answer (score 0):

If it's a scoping issue it might not be webpack related but react doing some [autobinding](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#under-the-hood-autobinding-and-event-delegation) magic in such a way that it's not compatible with how the jquery plugin works.

If that's truly the case, you could tweak the fullcalendar code for the calls to `callback()` and `complete()` to `callback.call(this)` and `complete.call(this)` so that the expected context is set every time.

Modifying the plugin source is not a particularly appealing solution, but it should get you by in a pinch.